# Canceling the scrolling animation when keyboard pops up on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a `UIViewController` that contains `UITextField`. I set the `inputAccessory` of the textfield to a `UIToolbar` that I create.
My ViewController's view is inside a `UIScrollView` (To handle the events of keyboard popping up)

Before:

[image: Before]
Now, when the keyboard pops up, suddenly my ScrollView is setting it's `contentOffset.y` to 64 with animation, so part of my view is pushed above the top of the screen:

After:

[image: After]

This is done by the framework because I'm using a toolbar for inputAccessoryView.
If i'm dropping the toolbar there is no animation and no content offset.

Is anyone knows how can I disable this automatic animation and scrolling?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of boolean flags and your `UIScrollViewDelegate` to prevent the scrolling from taking place. Scroll view delegates can be used to detect when scrolling is taking place, modify the type of scrolling, and also simply prevent it from happening, so your best approach is probably to look into detecting when the keyboard goes up (via a notification or text field delegate, whichever is more appropriate) and using that in combination with your scroll view delegate.

Comment: will the delegate method still be called if the content offset is changed?